# SQL Alchemy : what is the 'u' in the selection query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In the documentation to sqlalchemy the selection example is this:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#selecting

```
>>> for row in result:
...     print(row)
(1, u'jack', u'Jack Jones')
(2, u'wendy', u'Wendy Williams')
```

What does the character 'u' indicate here? Also, curiously, my friend gets the 'u' character, but I do not, reading from the local copies of the same sqllite db.

Thanks!

Comment: it's for unicode

Comment: This is a reminder that Python 2 will not maintained beyond 2019 and you should consider **u**pgrading soon. Or other might just say it is the syntax for unicode strings. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Really answers why my friend sees it and I do not.